# Vector tiles from non-earth coordinates

Tags: python, coordinate-system, leaflet, geojson, vector-tiles

I have a GeoJSON representing a fantasy world, with coordinates ranging from -3000 to 3000.

I have successfully displayed it on a Leaflet map using L.CRS.simple, but the GeoJSON is too heavy and takes too much time to load / requires too much memory.

I would like to convert the GeoJSON to vector tiles but I don't know of any tile server that would allow me to load tiles that are not in EPSG 4326 or 3857.

How could I create such tiles and render them on my map in CRS.simple?

I have tried scaling the coordinates with geopandas, to fit in the WGS84 coordinate bounds, but when loaded into something like Mapbox, it gets deformed as you get far from the "equator".